# psycopg2 - Function with multiple insert statements not commiting

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following PosgreSQL function with 2 insert statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(
    _username character varying,
    _email character varying,
    _password character varying,
    _first_name character varying,
    _middle_initial character,
    _last_name character varying,
    _title character varying,
    _enabled boolean,
    _company_id integer,
    _created_by integer,
    _superuser boolean)
  RETURNS UserAccount AS
$BODY$DECLARE
    result UserAccount;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO UserAccount
        (username, email, password, first_name, middle_initial,
        last_name, title, enabled, created_by, superuser)
    VALUES (_username, _email, _password, _first_name,_middle_initial,
        _last_name, _title, _enabled, _created_by, _superuser)
    RETURNING * INTO result;

    INSERT INTO UserCompany (user_id, company_id)
    VALUES (result.id, _company_id);

    RETURN result;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Executing `SELECT * FROM create_user(..._)` through PGAdmin works as expected and returns the new UserAccount row.

My Python code is as follows:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(app.config.get('POSTGRES_URI'))
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Some prep of variables...

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT
        id, username, email, first_name, middle_initial, last_name, last_login, title, failed_attempts, enabled, created_by, superuser
    FROM create_user(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (
        username, email, str(hashed_password), first_name, middle_initial, last_name,
        title, enabled, company_id, created_by, superuser
    ))

conn.commit()

user = dict(zip([x[0] for x in g.db.description], g.db.fetchone()))

cursor.close()
conn.close()

return user
```

This is returning all nulls for values and not committing the inserts. If I remove the second INSERT statement from the function, it works as expected. I've tried `conn.autocommit = True`, `conn.set_isolation_level(0)`, and using the cursor.callproc(...) method. Still doesn't work. Am I missing something or is this a problem with psycopg2 right now?

EDIT - Solution (facepalm):

I have discovered the problem to be the STRICT clause on the function. Nothing to do with pscyopg2. Feel dump for asking the question now. I was passing a null value to the function and, of course, that's what STRICT is meant to do when nulls are passed... nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't commit your  select statement in your Python script. The commit should occur in your PosgreSQL function. Try throwing a commit; above the RETURN line.

Comment: After adding a COMMIT to the function, I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (facepalm):

I have discovered the problem to be the STRICT clause on the function. Nothing to do with pscyopg2. Feel dump for asking the question now. I was passing a null value to the function and, of course, that's what STRICT is meant to do when nulls are passed... nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
create table UserAccount (
    id serial primary key, username text
);
create table UserCompany (
    user_id integer primary key,
    company_id integer
);
create or replace function create_user(
    _username character varying,
    _company_id integer
) returns UserAccount as $body$
declare
    result UserAccount;
begin
    insert into UserAccount (username)
    values (_username)
    returning * into result;

    insert into UserCompany (user_id, company_id)
    values (result.id, _company_id);

    return result;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql volatile strict;
```

Python code

```
from psycopg2 import connect
con = connect('dbname=cpn')
curs = con.cursor()
curs.execute('''
    select * from create_user(%s, %s);
''', ('john', 2))
con.commit()
user = curs.fetchone()
print user
con.close()
```

Returns

```
(2, 'john')
```